# How do I throw an exception in java?

Tags: java, exception

Hmm.. Here is the instruction given to me:

> Supports addition & subtraction with other Money object 
>   Throws exception if currencies are incompatible.

Hmm.. I already got a money class with add() in it. How exactly do I throw an exception in this case? I mean, I know how to do try{} catch but where am I supposed to do it? Do I do it on the same money class? or should the throwing of exceptions be done somewhere like in the main() where all other stuff takes place?

```
public class Money {

    Currency currency;
    int dollar;
    int cents;

    //constructor
    public Money(Currency currency, int dollar, int cents) {
        super();
        this.currency = currency;
        this.dollar = dollar;
        this.cents = cents;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    public Money add(Money moneyToBeAdded){
        Money result = new Money(moneyToBeAdded.getCurrency(),0,0);
        Money totalInCents;

        if(compareCurrency(moneyToBeAdded)){
            totalInCents = new Money(moneyToBeAdded.getCurrency(),0,(moneyToBeAdded.toCents() + cents));
            result = totalInCents.toDollars();
        }//to do convert currency

        return result;
    }

    public Money subtract()

    public boolean compareCurrency(Money money){
        return money.currency.equals(currency);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of resources available on this that can be found with a [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+throw+an+exception+in+java), have none of those helped you?

Comment: I guess I was just unsure of how to go about it. :) Come on, don't be so harsh about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good place to use an unchecked exception; any attempt to add incompatible monies is due to a programming error. So I'd suggest:

```
if (!compareCurrency(moneyToBeAdded))
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Mismatched currencies.");
```

Since `IllegalArgumentException` derives from `RuntimeException`, you don't need to declare that the `add()` method can throw it.

Do *not* create a custom subclass of `RuntimeException`. Custom exception types are useful when an application is trying to recover from a specific error, rather than just using the same logging or alert mechanism to handle every exception. Programs shouldn't try to recover from specific programming errors like this.

Answer (score 4):

```
throw new Exception("Currencies are incompatible");
```

However, I'd consider creating an app- or `Money`-specific exception instead, subclassing either `Exception` or `RuntimeException` depending on your needs.

Perhaps a `MoneyConversionException` extending `MoneyException` if things have to be granular.

Comment: This is a good place for an unchecked exception, but custom runtime exceptions are a bad idea. They encourage leaky abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there are loads of resources at your disposal (e.g. [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)). Anyway, that aside, I'd be wary of throwing a custom exception. Instead, throw an existing one (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`) so as to minimize complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A method that is supposed to throw any `Exception` needs a throw clause:

```
public Money add(Money moneyToBeAdded) throws MoneyException{..}
```

In the method, you need to filter out the cases where you want the exception to be thrown (with if-clauses for example) and then go:

```
throw new MoneyException("don't like that currency");
```

In this example, MoneyException is a class that extends Exception:

```
class MoneyException extends Exception {..}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Lesson from Oracle website

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception is about reporting an error, and it has to be declared as part of the method declaration.  For example:

```
class SomeMoneyProblem extends Exception {
      public SomeMoneyProblem() {
            super();
      }

      public SomeMoneyProblem(String msg) {
            super(msg);
      }
}

    public class Money {

       ...

       public Money() { 

       }

       public Money someMoneyMethod(Money moreMoney) throws SomeMoneyProblem {
               ....
               if ( someProblemCondition )
                      throw new SomeMoneyProblem();

               if ( someOtherProblem ) 
                      throw new SomeMoneyProblem("Other Problem");

       }

       public static void main() {

               Money m = new Money();
               try {
                    m.someMoneyMethod();
               } catch (SomeMoneyProblem p) {
                    System.err.println(p);
               }
       }
    }
```